# difference between 2>&1 | tee output.log and |& tee output.log

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection

I wanted to know the difference between the following two commands

```
2>&1 | tee output.log
```

and

```
|& tee output.log
```

Looking for pipes to save command's output I've reached [this explanation](https://askubuntu.com/a/731237/511836).
I've been using the former, but now I wonder if the latter saves typing with same result or there's something I don't understand (or I don't know).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`man bash`

> If `|&` is used, command's standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to command2's standard input through the pipe; **it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`**.

So no difference.